# Problem in compiling the .tex file while using \usepackage{amssymb,amsmath} in TeXstudio (edited)

Tags: amsmath, texstudio, ieeetran, amsthm, amssymb

Me and my professor together writing a paper for IEEE Transactions on signal processing. He gave me my paper's .tex and .pdf files to make some changes. But I could not compile the given .tex file even though my professor could compile the file on his computer. Then I  noticed that my professor was using `\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}.` After that, I replaced the same with `\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}`, and to my surprise, my .tex file got compiled in one go. But the problem is that by doing so, the number of pages of corresponding .pdf file increased, which is undesirable. In addition to that, with `\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}` , my professor is not able to compile the .tex file on his computer. He is very angry with me because he thinks I messed up the .tex file which he sent to me.

Here is the compilation error I am getting:

```
Environment proof undefined. \begin{proof}
\begin{document} ended by \end{proof}. \end{proof}
Environment proof undefined. \begin{proof}
\begin{document} ended by \end{proof}. \end{proof}
Environment proof undefined. \begin{proof}
\begin{document} ended by \end{proof}. \end{proof}
Environment proof undefined. \begin{proof}
\begin{document} ended by \end{proof}. \end{proof}
Unknown document class (or package),(caption) standard defaults will be used.
Overfull \hbox (3.33931pt too wide) detected
Underfull \hbox (badness 2884) in paragraph
Obsolete command \bold; \mathbf should be used instead
Overfull \hbox (18.37825pt too wide) in paragraph
Underfull \hbox (badness 5817) in paragraph
```

Here is the template of my paper:

```
        \documentclass[final]{IEEEtran}
    \IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
    %
    %\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
    %\bibliography{IEEEabrv,mybibfile}
    % \overrideIEEEmargins                      
    \setlength{\textheight}{237mm}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    %\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}
    \usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{epstopdf}
    \usepackage{romannum}
    \usepackage{algorithm}
    \usepackage{subcaption}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{multicol}
    \usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
    \usepackage{romannum}
    \input{notation.tex}
    
    % \def\oneb{\mathbf{1}}
    % \def\R{{\mathbb R}}
    % \newcommand{\qed}{\hfill $\Box$}
    
    \def\ct{\tilde{c}}
    \def\Dcal{{\cal D}}
    \def\DBP{\D_{{\rm BP}}}
    \def\db{\bar{d}}
    % \def\oneb{\mathbf{1}}
    % \def\R{{\mathbb R}}
    \def\yb{\bar{y}}
    
    \def\cb{\bar{c}}
    \def\ct{\tilde{c}}
    \def\Gsupp{{\rm Gsupp}}
    \def\dmax{d_{{\rm max}} }
    \def\dmin{d_{{\rm min}} }
    
    \def\Rcal{{\cal R}}
    
    \def\boldr{{\bf r}}
    \def\cons{{\mbox{const}}}
    
    
    \newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}{\bf}{\it}
    \newtheorem{definition}{Definition}{\bf}{\it}
    \newtheorem{example}{Example}{\bf}{\rm}
    \newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}{\bf}{\it}
    \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}{\bf}{\it}
    \newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}{\bf}{\it}
    \newtheorem{conjecture}{Conjecture}{\bf}{\it}
    \newtheorem{problem}{Problem}{\bf}{\rm}
    
    \begin{document}

    \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

\bibliography{Comp-Sens}

% \cleardoublepage

\end{document}
```

Here is my 'notation.tex' file:

```
% This file contains the notation for the book on hidden Markov processes.
% Latest update on 15.08.09, rearranging, grouping, and getting rid of
% unnecessary definitions.

% Bold face Roman symbols

\def\oneb{{\bf 1}}

\def\a{{\bf a}}
\def\b{{\bf b}}
\def\c{{\bf c}}
\def\dd{{\bf d}}
\def\eb{{\bf e}}
\def\f{{\bf f}}
\def\gbold{{\bf g}}
\def\h{{\bf h}}
\def\i{{\bf i}}
\def\j{{\bf j}}
\def\k{{\bf k}}
\def\p{{\bf p}}
\def\q{{\bf q}}
\def\rbold{{\bf r}}
\def\u{{\bf u}}
\def\v{{\bf v}}
\def\w{{\bf w}}
\def\x{{\bf x}}
\def\y{{\bf y}}
\def\z{{\bf z}}
\def\Z{{\bf Z}}

% Calligraphic symbols

\def\A{{\cal A}}
\def\B{{\cal B}}
\def\C{{\cal C}}
\def\Dcal{{\cal D}}
\def\E{{\cal E}}
\def\F{{\cal F}}
\def\G{{\cal G}}
\def\H{{\cal H}}
\def\I{{\cal I}}
\def\Lcal{{\cal L}}
\def\M{{\cal M}}
\def\N{{\cal N}}
\def\P{{\cal P}}
\def\Q{{\cal Q}}
\def\Rcal{{\cal R}}
\def\S{{\cal S}}
\def\T{{\cal T}}
\def\U{{\cal U}}
\def\V{{\cal V}}
\def\X{{\cal X}}
\def\Y{{\cal Y}}
\def\Zcal{{\cal Z}}

% Blackboard style symbols

\def\Abb{{\mathbb A}}
\def\Bbb{{\mathbb B}}
\def\Cbb{{\mathbb C}}
\def\Fbb{{\mathbb F}}
\def\Mbb{{\mathbb M}}
\def\Nbb{{\mathbb N}}
\def\Nm{{\mathbb N}}
\def\R{{\mathbb R}}
\def\Sbb{{\mathbb S}}
\def\Sm{{\mathbb S}}
\def\Xbb{{\mathbb X}}
\def\Ybb{{\mathbb Y}}
\def\Zbb{{\mathbb Z}}
\def\Zm{{\mathbb Z}}

% Abbreviations for greek letters

\def\al{\alpha}
\def\d{\delta}
\def\D{\Delta}
\def\e{\epsilon}
\def\g{\gamma}
\def\GA{\Gamma}
\def\l{\lambda}
\def\L{\Lambda}
\def\om{\omega}
\def\OM{\Omega}
\def\r{\rho}
\def\s{\sigma}
\def\SI{\Sigma}
\def\t{\tau}
\def\th{\theta}
\def\Th{\Theta}

% Bold greek letters

\def\balpha{{\boldsymbol \alpha}}
\def\bbeta{{\boldsymbol \beta}}
\def\boldeta{{\boldsymbol \eta}}
\def\bgamma{{\boldsymbol \gamma}}
\def\bl{{\boldsymbol \lambda}}
\def\bmu{{\boldsymbol \mu}}
\def\bnu{{\boldsymbol \nu}}
\def\bth{{\boldsymbol \theta}}
\def\bphi{{\boldsymbol \phi}}
\def\bpsi{{\boldsymbol \psi}}
\def\bpi{{\boldsymbol \pi}}
\def\bsig{{\boldsymbol \sigma}}

% Bars, hats, tildes etc.

\def\ab{\bar{a}}
\def\ah{\hat{\a}}
\def\Ab{\bar{A}}
\def\Bb{\bar{\B}}
\def\bmuh{\hat{\bmu}}
\def\cb{\bar{c}}
\def\dh{\hat{d}}
\def\Eh{\hat{E}}
\def\fb{\bar{f}}
\def\fh{\hat{f}}
\def\kb{\bar{k}}
\def\pb{\bar{p}}
\def\ph{\hat{p}}
\def\Pb{\bar{P}}
\def\PB{\bar{\cal P}}
\def\Ph{\hat{P}}
\def\Pt{\tilde{P}}
\def\Ptt{\tilde{\P}}
\def\qb{\bar{q}}
\def\Qt{\tilde{Q}}
\def\rbar{\bar{\rho}}
\def\Sb{\bar{S}}
\def\ub{\bar{u}}
\def\vb{\bar{v}}
\def\xb{\bar{x}}
\def\xt{\tilde{x}}
\def\yb{\bar{y}}
\def\zb{\bar{z}}
\def\zt{\tilde{z}}

\def\lb{\bar{\l}}
\def\nub{\bar{\nu}}
\def\thb{\bar{\theta}}

% Approaching infinity

\def\kai{k \ap \infty}
\def\lai{l \ap \infty}
\def\mai{m \ap \infty}
\def\nai{n \ap \infty}
\def\tai{t \ap \infty}
\def\Tai{T \ap \infty}

% Miscellaneous mathematical symbols

\def\ap{\rightarrow}
\def\arg{{\rm arg}}
\def\lip{\langle}
\def\rip{\rangle}
\def\es{\emptyset}
\def\seq{\subseteq}
\def\dag{\dagger}

\def\bi{\{0,1\}}
\def\bim{\bi^m}
\def\bin{\bi^n}
\def\bimn{\bi^{m \times n}}
\def\bp{\{-1,1\}}
\def\bz{{\bf 0}}
\def\imp{\; \Longrightarrow \;}
\def\orr{\vee}
\def\fa{\; \forall}
\def\mult{x_1 , \ldots , x_m}
\def\xvec{[ x_1 \ldots x_m ]^t}

\def\half{\frac{1}{2}}
\def\st{\mbox{ s.t. }}
\def\sg{\mbox{sign}}
\def\nm{\Vert}
\def\mgf{{\rm mgf}}

\renewcommand{\iff}{\mbox{$\; \; \Longleftrightarrow \; \;$}}
\renewcommand{\and}{\mbox{$\wedge$}}

% Typesetting commands

\newcommand{\bc}{\begin{center}}
\newcommand{\ec}{\end{center}}
\newcommand{\be}{\begin{equation}}
\newcommand{\ee}{\end{equation}}
\newcommand{\bd}{\begin{displaymath}}
\newcommand{\ed}{\end{displaymath}}
\newcommand{\ba}{\begin{array}}
\newcommand{\ea}{\end{array}}
\newcommand{\ben}{\begin{enumerate}}
\newcommand{\een}{\end{enumerate}}
\newcommand{\bit}{\begin{itemize}}
\newcommand{\eit}{\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\beq}{\begin{eqnarray}}
\newcommand{\eeq}{\end{eqnarray}}
\newcommand{\btab}{\begin{tabular}}
\newcommand{\etab}{\end{tabular}}
\newcommand{\bfig}{\begin{figure}}
\newcommand{\efig}{\end{figure}}
\newcommand{\btp}{\begin{tikzpicture}}
\newcommand{\etp}{\end{tikzpicture}}

% Environment commands

% \newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}{\bf}{\it}
% \newtheorem{definition}{Definition}{\bf}{\it}
% \newtheorem{example}{Example}{\bf}{\rm}
% \newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}{\bf}{\it}
% \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}{\bf}{\it}
% \newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}{\bf}{\it}
% \newtheorem{conjecture}{Conjecture}{\bf}{\it}
% \newtheorem{problem}{Problem}{\bf}{\rm}

% Additional commands for compressed sensing papers

\newcommand{\argmin}{\operatornamewithlimits{arg min}}
\newcommand{\argmax}{\operatornamewithlimits{arg max}}
\renewcommand{\mod}{~{\rm mod}~}

% \DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
% \DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}

\def\boldr{{\bf r}}
\def\cons{{\mbox{const}}}

% Norm symbols

\newcommand{\nmm}[1]{ \nm #1 \nm }
\newcommand{\nmeu}[1]{ \nm #1 \nm_2 }
\newcommand{\nmeusq}[1]{ \nm #1 \nm_2^2 }
\newcommand{\nmA}[1]{ \nm #1 \nm_A }
\newcommand{\nmF}[1]{ \nm #1 \nm_F }
\newcommand{\nmM}[1]{ \nm #1 \nm_M }
\newcommand{\nmN}[1]{ \nm #1 \nm_N }
\newcommand{\nmP}[1]{ \nm #1 \nm_P }
\newcommand{\nmS}[1]{ \nm #1 \nm_S }
\newcommand{\nmp}[1]{ \nm #1 \nm_p }
\newcommand{\nmq}[1]{ \nm #1 \nm_q }
\newcommand{\nmv}[1]{ \nm #1 \nm_v }
\newcommand{\nmcmu}[1]{ \nm #1 \nm_{C,\mu} }
\newcommand{\nmgmu}[1]{ \nm #1 \nm_{{\rm SGL},\mu} }

% Inner product symbol
\newcommand{\IP}[2]{ \langle #1 , #2 \rangle }

% Combinatorial parameter symbol
\newcommand{\nchk}[2]{ \left( \ba{c} #1 \\ #2 \ea \right) }
% Legendre symbol
\newcommand{\Leg}[2]{ \left( \frac{#1}{#2} \right) }

\newcommand{\halmos}{\hfill $\Box$}


% \newcommand{\det}{{\rm det}}
\newcommand{\rk}{{\rm{rank}}}
\newcommand{\supp}{{\rm{supp}}}
\newcommand{\tr}{{\rm{tr}}}
% \newcommand{\mod}{\rm{ mod }}

\def\Jh{\hat{J}}

\def\vcd{\mbox{VC-dim}}

\def\Cm{\Cbb^m}
\def\Cn{\Cbb^n}
\def\Cr{\Cbb^r}
\def\Cs{\Cbb^s}
\def\Ckl{\Cbb^{k \times l}}
\def\Cmn{\Cbb^{m \times n}}
\def\Cmr{\Cbb^{m \times r}}
\def\Cno{\Cbb^{n_1 \times n_2}}
\def\Cns{\Cbb^{n \times s}}
\def\Crr{\Cbb^{r \times r}}
\def\Crs{\Cbb^{r \times s}}
\def\Fm{\Fbb_2^m}
\def\Fmn{\Fbb_2^{m \times n}}
\def\Fn{\Fbb_2^n}
\def\Fp{\Fbb_p}
\def\Fq{\Fbb_q}
\def\Fqs{\Fbb_q^*}
\def\PGq{PGL(2,\Fq)}
\def\PSq{PSL(2,\Fq)}
\def\PScq{PSL^c(2,\Fq)}
\def\Rkl{\R^{k \times l}}
\def\Rmn{\R^{m \times n}}
\def\Rno{\R^{n_1 \times n_2}}

\def\ulo{u_{\L_0}}
\def\uloc{u_{\L_0^c}}
\def\vlo{v_{\L_0}}
\def\vloc{v_{\L_0^c}}
\def\xd{x_\downarrow}
\def\xh{\hat{x}}
\def\Xh{\hat{X}}
\def\xl{x_{\L}}
\def\xlc{x_{\L^c}}
\def\xlo{x_{\L_0}}
\def\xloc{x_{\L_0^c}}
\def\hl{h_{\L}}
\def\hlc{h_{\L^c}}
\def\hlo{h_{\L_0}}
\def\hloc{h_{\L_0^c}}
\def\hso{h_{S_0}}
\def\hsoc{h_{S_0^c}}

\def\GkS{{\rm GkS}}
\def\ru{\underline{\r}}
\def\rb{\bar{\r}}



\def\nmsl1{\nm_{{\rm SL1}}}
```

Can anybody help me in resolving this issue? I am using TeXstudio 2.12.14 (git 2.12.14)
Using Qt Version 5.8.0, compiled with Qt 5.8.0 R.

Comment: you have not provided any information that would allow anyone to help. Naturally  if the document uses ams theorem commands and you do not load the package you will get errors. texstudio, git, Qt are not relevant.

Comment: "not able to compile the .tex file" is not a useful description. Show the exact error from the log, in a code block in your question

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ; I just edited my question. I will appreciate your input.

Comment: `! LaTeX Error: File \`notation.tex' not found`

Comment: if I remove `\input{notation.tex}` your example gives no error

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ; Just added 'notation.tex' file. in the above question. I can't remove this file.

Comment: wow all those `\bf`, `\bf` has not been defined by default in latex since 1993, when was that file written???

Comment: the ieeetran.cls removed proof in 2012 (according to the changelog-file). Ask your professor how old his tex system is and which ieeetran.cls version he uses (look e.g. into the log-file).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ; All those \bf has been defined by my professor. It was written in the last decade. My professor is a member of the royal society  And currently, he is the national science chair of India.

Comment: your example does not have `proof` anywhere, does the error you show really come from the code you posted?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ; I did not share the main content of my paper in my question. However, in my original .tex file, I have used \begin{proof}, \end{proof}.

Comment: so you have an error in code you have not shown,  which makes it hard to help but see Ulrike's comment check which version of ieee class you each have

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ; Ok, I am going to share my original file in my question.

Comment: don't post your research paper here, but you should post _an example of the problem_.

Comment: have you checked the ieee class version as suggested

Comment: @shashankranjan -- Please get a copy of your professor's log, and compare the version numbers of *everything* that's loaded with what's reported in your log.  That should allow you to identify what is causing the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding `\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}{\bf}{\it}`. I have added it and it compiles. I have TexLive.

Comment: it compiles without that as posted

Comment: Without it I get `! LaTeX Error: Environment proof undefined.`.

Comment: @xpicto ; I cant add \newtheorem{proof}{Proof}{\bf}{\it} as it will not compile on my professor's laptop. My professor can compile my .tex file with no problem.

Comment: but the example posted does not use `proof` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ; In the example, I am not using proof. But in my original file I am using proof.

Comment: If your code is not what you've posted, then posting the error message is misleading at best.